# queued up requests are not sent to server (jpos QMUX)

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

below is my client mux config. I am facing the problem that when I send 100 requests, only the first 5 are reached to the server and I am able to get the response within 100 ms.my understanding is as soon as I got the response mux is supposed to send the remaining request to the server but it is not happening so all the rest of the 95 request gets a null response from the call to `mux.request(msg,25000)`.

**10_client_channel.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<channel-adaptor name="manager"
                 class="org.jpos.q2.iso.MultiSessionChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
    <in>channel-Tx</in>
    <out>channel-Rx</out>
    <sessions>5</sessions>
    <timeout>30000</timeout>
    <keep-alive>yes</keep-alive>
    <max-connect-attempts>30000000000</max-connect-attempts>
    <reconnect-delay>100</reconnect-delay>
   

    <channel name="client-channel" class="org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel" logger="Q2"
             packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager">
        <filter class="org.jpos.iso.filter.DebugFilter" direction="outgoing"/>
                <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="port" value="65000"/>
        <property name="timeout" value="60000"/>
 
        <property name="packager-config" value="${catalina.base}/conf/esewa/isoproperties/iso8583f1soft.xml"/>
    </channel>

</channel-adaptor>
```

**20_client_qmux.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="jpos-client-mux">
    <in>channel-Rx</in>
    <out>channel-Tx</out>
    <ready>jpos-client-adaptor.ready</ready>
    <key>11,37</key>
    <unhandled>Channel-unhandled</unhandled>
</mux>
```

`private QMUX qmux;` is defined as a global variable and initialized via the constructor like:

> `qmux= NameRegistrar.get("mux.jpos-client-mux");  channelTimeoutPeriod=25000;`

Below are the rest of the relevant codes as per @Andrés Alcarraz `s request

```java
            log.info("firing ISO....");
            applicationResponse.setIsoRequestTime(new Date());
            ISOMsg responseISOMessage= qmux.request(requestISOMessage,channelTimeoutPeriod);
            applicationResponse.setIsoResponseTime(new Date());
            log.info("responseISOMessage:{}",responseISOMessage);
```

Comment: Hi Shannon, can you show the code that is sending the requests, I would suspect the problem comes from that part, and without it, it seems unlikely someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Sanjok, thank you for updating your question, The number of `sessions` is 5, and it matches the number of responses you receive before receiving a `null`. That can give a hint about the problem, don't know where it can lead yet. It would be better if you cold share a complete reproducible program, since there are a number of factors that could lead to what you are seeing. A few of them may depend on the values of the fields of the messages you are sending, and we are not seeing that information in this question. Maybe you could add the log of what you see as an advance?

Comment: May I ask why are you using `MultiSessionChannelAdaptor` instead of the plain `ChannelAdaptor`? I haven't seen this one being frequently used, and in the project's git log, it doesn't seem to be highly maintained, so, it could be a bug here or there. Would you mind testing the `ChannelAdaptor` instead and see if the problem persists? Although it would be nice to hunt a possible bug, it would be better to first validate there is one by using another more common component.

Comment: I am choosing `MultiSessionChannelAdaptor` over  `ChannelAdaptor` because the Bank\`s CBS is taking 10 sec to respond to my application. Due to this too many transactions are getting qued up on my end. Using `ChannelAdaptor` shows synchronous behavior. A tech person from the bank is saying their CBS supports only persistent TCP connections.

Comment: But, can you test with the normal channel adaptor to discard or not if it's an issue with multi session channel adaptor? I tried replacing a channel adaptor by a multi session channel adaptor in a test project and didn't see that issue, but as I told you without the code that generates the messages or the values of their fields and responses it's hard to tell if it's some combination of things. A lot extract would be helpful

Comment: "my understanding is as soon as I got the response mux is supposed to send the remaining request to the server" Actually, this is not true, the mux sends the request through the channel as soon as you call the request method, it doesn't directly send it, it put it in the `in` queue of the channel adaptor, and it is supposed to be taken by it independently of another request being answered, since the channel doesn't know about matching requests to responses.

Comment: Watch out your MUX's `ready` element, it shows: `<ready>jpos-client-adaptor.ready</ready>` so it expects your channel-adaptor to be called `jpos-client-adaptor`, but your channel-adaptor is actually called `manager`.

Make sure your remote host actually supports multiple sessions to the same port, I believe they don't, and you're just connected from a TCP/IP standpoint against the low level TCP/IP stack's backlog, and that's why you're not getting any response. Some sessions are actually connected to nothing.

Comment: Hi Andrés, I tested the same, running the jpos server in my test environment. I did not find the issue we were talking about. But, when I switch to their server problem is visible. I am not aware of any special request handling mechanism required on the server side for `MultiSessionChannelAdaptor`.

Comment: Hi, have you try to set keep-alive "No" ?


On ASCIIChannel.getMessageLength() method, calling serverOut.write and serverOut flush withoud synchronized(serverOutLock). so the byte that be sent will  mixed on another messages